# How to code a working struct?

Tags: solidity

I have tried a lot of combinations of the following code but nothing updates the students array.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {

  uint public test=9;
  struct Student {
    uint age;
    uint income;
    uint score;
    uint attendance;
  }
  Student[] public students;
  uint public studentCount=0;

  function setStudent (uint _age, uint _income, uint _score, uint _attendance) public {
    test=19;
    students.push(Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance}));    
  }    
}
```

It does not give an error but it does not ever modify students. Has anyone any idea about this?

I am testing in geth:

```
> con.setStudent(1,1,1,1)
"0x3bf6788c442a8495286cfccf7f8b18250cf1577a59b0d57e6a24b7e892dd2365"

 > con.students(0)
[0, 0, 0, 0]

> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009"
> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,1)
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"


con = eth.contract(abi).at(addr)
```

I tried a lot of combinations of code but nothing updates students.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this now. The error was with gas and uint. I changed the code to unit16 for the variables and it finally worked.

I had a warning in Remix about gas and then I tried changing the unit. Final code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {

  uint public test=9;
  struct Student {
    uint16 age;
    uint16 income;
    uint16 score;
    uint16 attendance;
  }
  Student[] public students;
  uint public studentCount=0;

  function setStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance) public {
    test=19;
    Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attend
ance});
    students.push(tempStudent);
    //students.push(Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance}));
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using web3.js(node REPL,Web) for calling your methods.

If you are, check your calls. if you are using this format :

`ContractInstance.setStudent.call(...,{gas:3000000, from :0x....})`

instead Of

`ContractInstance.setStudent(...,{gas:3000000, from :0x....})`

where `ContractInstance` is the instance you get after deployment.

if you are using the first way of calling `setStudent()` then no storage modification will be done. Calls are basically readonly that usually don't require a lot of gas (they sometimes can, so adding the gas option and the from is always better ), so they don't modify storage.

If you are not using web3.js then please post more client code.

Comment: I added the geth code.

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA3 {

    struct Student {
        uint age;
        uint income;
        uint score;
        uint attendance;
    }

    Student[] public students;
    uint public studentCount=0;

    function setStudent (uint _age, uint _income, uint _score, uint _attendance) public {
        Student memory tempStudent = Student(_age, _income, _score, _attendance);
        students.push(tempStudent);
    }
}
```

The code above correctly updates the student's struct array.

This also worked:

```
    function setStudent (uint _age, uint _income, uint _score, uint _attendance) public {
        Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance});
        students.push(tempStudent);
    }
```

And finally your original code worked as well in Remix:

```
   function setStudent (uint _age, uint _income, uint _score, uint _attendance) public {
        //Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance});
        students.push(Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance}));
    }
```

I'd say your code should work, and the problem lies within how you're calling these functions in geth.

Let me run in geth and update my findings...

Comment: This must be a storage allocation issue then or related to actual variable values - or version numbers. I am using the latest compiler. I just tested again and the same error happens.

Comment: I had this in Remix - Gas requirement of function CA3.setStudent(uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256) high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage) - maybe this is the issue. The gas limits do not work and the function never executes.

Comment: I tested with the version, in Remix, that you had defined in your code. 0.4.18 and it worked without issue or alteration. Still haven't tested in geth, yet. I see you got it to work though. I'll try in remix with the latest version.

Comment: I just re-tested and the problem was the unit and gas. I assume in your remix there are different gas limits. But basically the unit takes up 32 bytes and that was causing the issues apparently.

Comment: using the very latest build, 0.4.21 it failed on invalid opcode. 0.4.20 did work as I posted.

What you posted earlier, about the gas requirement is just a warning.

Comment: changing to uint16 did cause it to work. So this must have been some kind of gas issue.

Comment: I typoed the test - it also worked in 0.4.21 without issue.

What you posted about earlier is a warning - I get those as well at times and my code works as intended. 

I highly doubt this is a gas issue as it doesn't remotely even come close to running out of gas. It used 123,192 units to do a setStudent() call. 

Also, Nico reported your code worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

contract works fine indeed , tested in Remix. 
Please do note that studentCount is an unused variable.